# All Posts Have The Same Comments

Tags: wp-query, widgets, comments

I'm getting a really weird bug. I'm getting the same comments from 1 specific post which is the "Hello world" for every single post! But when I remove a bit of code for a recent posts widget that I'm trying to create, this bug disappears... here's the code of the recent posts widget:

```
class Hype_Recent_Posts extends WP_Widget {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'hype_rp', // Base ID
            __('Paradox Recent Posts', 'hype'), // Name
            array( 'description' => __( 'Display your recent posts, with a Thumbnail.', 'hype' ), ) // Args
        );
    }

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
        $no_of_posts = apply_filters( 'no_of_posts', $instance['no_of_posts'] );

        echo $args['before_widget'];

        if ( ! empty( $title ) )
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

        // WP_Query arguments
        $qa = array (
            'post_type'              => 'post',
            'posts_per_page'         => 5,
            'offset'                 => 0,
            'ignore_sticky_posts'    => 1

        );

        // The Query
        $recent_articles_wtb = new WP_Query( $qa );
        if($recent_articles_wtb->have_posts()) : ?>
        <ul class="rp">
        <?php
            while($recent_articles_wtb->have_posts()) : 
            $recent_articles_wtb->the_post();
         ?>

                 <li class='rp-item'>
                 <?php if( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
                 <div class='rp-thumb'><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></a></div>
                 <?php else : ?>
                 <div class='rp-thumb'><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/9viqf41.jpg"><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i></a></div>
                 <?php endif; ?>    
                 <div class='rp-title'><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                 </li>

        <?php
              endwhile;
           else: 
        ?>

              Oops, there are no posts.

        <?php
           endif;
        ?>
        </ul>
        <?php

        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
            $title = $instance[ 'title' ];
        }
        else {
            $title = __( 'Latest Articles', 'hype' );
        }
        if ( isset( $instance[ 'no_of_posts' ] ) ) {
            $no_of_posts = $instance[ 'no_of_posts' ];
        }
        else {
            $no_of_posts = __( '5', 'hype' );
        }
        ?>
        <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:','hype' ); ?></label> 
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />

        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'no_of_posts' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'No. of Posts:', 'hype' ); ?></label>
        <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'no_of_posts' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'no_of_posts' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $no_of_posts ); ?>" />
        </p>
        <?php 
    }

    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';
        $instance['no_of_posts'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['no_of_posts'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['no_of_posts'] ) : '5';
        if ( is_numeric($new_instance['no_of_posts']) == false ) {
            $instance['no_of_posts'] = $old_instance['no_of_posts'];
            }
        return $instance;


    }
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'register_hype_widget' );  
function register_hype_widget() {  
    register_widget( 'Hype_Recent_Posts' );  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are stomping on the global wordpress posts with your plugin.

Doing your wp_query call and then calling

```
$recent_articles_wtb->the_post();
```

means that later (after your loop), you will want to call

```
wp_reset_postdata(); # Thanks Milo
```

That should reset the global $current_post and $post objects.

Comment: I think you want `wp_reset_postdata()`, not `rewind_posts()`.

Comment: Milo's answer did the job, I tried the `rewind_posts();` but it was taking too long to load the page, so I tried `wp_reset_postdata();` suggested by @Milo and this problem disappeared. Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Thanks Milo. Updating. I never do things that way so I occasionally forget which is which.